# how to parse this json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

i am newbie to JavaScript, and i want to parse a JSON returned by Web Service.I have searched many links but didn't find this type of JSON parsing in JavaScript,So can anyone help me in parsing this type JSON?

here is my code and JSON.
**JS**

```
 $http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: API_HOST + '/webservice/Get_FilterDetails',
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     'caymanauth': caymanauth
   },
   data: '&Catid=' + Catid

 }).success(function(data) {



 }).error(function() {
   alert("error");
 });
```

**JSON from Web Service**

```
{
  "Status": "1",
  "Details": [
    "Rate Type", [{
      "intGlCode": "6",
      "fk_CatList": "1",
      "varName": "$",
      "intDisplayOrder": "1"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "7",
      "fk_CatList": "1",
      "varName": "$$",
      "intDisplayOrder": "2"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "8",
      "fk_CatList": "1",
      "varName": "$$$",
      "intDisplayOrder": "3"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "9",
      "fk_CatList": "1",
      "varName": "$$$$",
      "intDisplayOrder": "4"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "10",
      "fk_CatList": "1",
      "varName": "$$$$$",
      "intDisplayOrder": "5"
    }],
    "Listing Type", [{
      "intGlCode": "1",
      "fk_CatList": "2",
      "varName": "*",
      "intDisplayOrder": "1"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "2",
      "fk_CatList": "2",
      "varName": "**",
      "intDisplayOrder": "2"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "3",
      "fk_CatList": "2",
      "varName": "***",
      "intDisplayOrder": "3"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "4",
      "fk_CatList": "2",
      "varName": "****",
      "intDisplayOrder": "4"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "5",
      "fk_CatList": "2",
      "varName": "*****",
      "intDisplayOrder": "5"
    }],
    "Area", [{
      "intGlCode": "32",
      "varCityName": "Camana Bay",
      "intDisplayOrder": "1",
      "dtCreatedDate": "2014-10-21 02:44:57",
      "dtModifyDate": "2015-07-07 02:50:13",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "varIPAddress": "208.168.244.109",
      "varAdminUser": "Cayman After Work"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "1",
      "varCityName": "Breakers",
      "intDisplayOrder": "2",
      "dtCreatedDate": "2014-09-06 10:20:57",
      "dtModifyDate": "2014-10-10 01:56:48",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "varIPAddress": "192.168.1.134",
      "varAdminUser": "Netclues"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "2",
      "varCityName": "Grand Cayman",
      "intDisplayOrder": "3",
      "dtCreatedDate": "2014-09-06 10:21:04",
      "dtModifyDate": "2014-10-10 01:59:24",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "varIPAddress": "192.168.1.134",
      "varAdminUser": "Netclues"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "16",
      "varCityName": "Bodden Town",
      "intDisplayOrder": "4",
      "dtCreatedDate": "2014-09-06 10:21:19",
      "dtModifyDate": "2014-10-17 12:27:33",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "varIPAddress": "192.168.1.134",
      "varAdminUser": "Netclues"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "15",
      "varCityName": "Cayman Brac",
      "intDisplayOrder": "5",
      "dtCreatedDate": "2014-09-06 10:21:12",
      "dtModifyDate": "2014-10-10 01:56:21",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "varIPAddress": "192.168.1.134",
      "varAdminUser": "Netclues"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "20",
      "varCityName": "East End",
      "intDisplayOrder": "6",
      "dtCreatedDate": "2014-10-10 01:57:06",
      "dtModifyDate": "2014-10-10 01:57:06",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "varIPAddress": "27.54.170.98",
      "varAdminUser": "Netclues"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "21",
      "varCityName": "George Town",
      "intDisplayOrder": "7",
      "dtCreatedDate": "2014-10-10 01:57:19",
      "dtModifyDate": "2014-10-10 01:57:19",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "varIPAddress": "27.54.170.98",
      "varAdminUser": "Netclues"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "22",
      "varCityName": "George Town West",
      "intDisplayOrder": "8",
      "dtCreatedDate": "2014-10-10 01:57:29",
      "dtModifyDate": "2014-10-10 01:57:29",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "varIPAddress": "27.54.170.98",
      "varAdminUser": "Netclues"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "23",
      "varCityName": "Little Cayman",
      "intDisplayOrder": "9",
      "dtCreatedDate": "2014-10-10 01:57:45",
      "dtModifyDate": "2014-10-10 01:57:45",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "varIPAddress": "27.54.170.98",
      "varAdminUser": "Netclues"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "24",
      "varCityName": "North Side",
      "intDisplayOrder": "10",
      "dtCreatedDate": "2014-10-10 01:57:55",
      "dtModifyDate": "2014-10-10 01:57:55",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "varIPAddress": "27.54.170.98",
      "varAdminUser": "Netclues"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "25",
      "varCityName": "Red Bay",
      "intDisplayOrder": "11",
      "dtCreatedDate": "2014-10-10 01:58:06",
      "dtModifyDate": "2014-10-10 01:58:06",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "varIPAddress": "27.54.170.98",
      "varAdminUser": "Netclues"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "26",
      "varCityName": "Rum Point/Cayman Kai",
      "intDisplayOrder": "12",
      "dtCreatedDate": "2014-10-10 01:58:16",
      "dtModifyDate": "2014-10-10 01:58:16",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "varIPAddress": "27.54.170.98",
      "varAdminUser": "Netclues"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "27",
      "varCityName": "Savannah",
      "intDisplayOrder": "13",
      "dtCreatedDate": "2014-10-10 01:58:25",
      "dtModifyDate": "2014-10-10 01:58:25",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "varIPAddress": "27.54.170.98",
      "varAdminUser": "Netclues"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "28",
      "varCityName": "Seven Mile Beach",
      "intDisplayOrder": "14",
      "dtCreatedDate": "2014-10-10 01:58:36",
      "dtModifyDate": "2014-10-10 01:58:42",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "varIPAddress": "27.54.170.98",
      "varAdminUser": "Netclues"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "29",
      "varCityName": "Sister Islands",
      "intDisplayOrder": "15",
      "dtCreatedDate": "2014-10-10 01:58:51",
      "dtModifyDate": "2014-10-10 01:58:51",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "varIPAddress": "27.54.170.98",
      "varAdminUser": "Netclues"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "30",
      "varCityName": "West Bay",
      "intDisplayOrder": "16",
      "dtCreatedDate": "2014-10-10 01:59:00",
      "dtModifyDate": "2014-10-10 01:59:00",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "varIPAddress": "27.54.170.98",
      "varAdminUser": "Netclues"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "31",
      "varCityName": "West Bay Road",
      "intDisplayOrder": "17",
      "dtCreatedDate": "2014-10-10 01:59:12",
      "dtModifyDate": "2014-10-10 01:59:12",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "varIPAddress": "27.54.170.98",
      "varAdminUser": "Netclues"
    }],
    "Cuisine", [{
      "intGlCode": "11",
      "fk_CatList": "4",
      "varName": "Pizza",
      "intDisplayOrder": "1"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "12",
      "fk_CatList": "4",
      "varName": "Hot Dog",
      "intDisplayOrder": "2"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "13",
      "fk_CatList": "4",
      "varName": "Take Out",
      "intDisplayOrder": "3"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "14",
      "fk_CatList": "4",
      "varName": "Caterers",
      "intDisplayOrder": "4"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "15",
      "fk_CatList": "4",
      "varName": "Asian",
      "intDisplayOrder": "5"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "16",
      "fk_CatList": "4",
      "varName": "American",
      "intDisplayOrder": "6"
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "17",
      "fk_CatList": "4",
      "varName": "Seafood",
      "intDisplayOrder": "7"
    }],
    "Categories", [{
      "intGlCode": "1",
      "fk_Category": "0",
      "fk_CatList": "1,2,3,4,5",
      "varName": "Restaurant",
      "varAlias": "restaurant",
      "chrImageFlag": "U",
      "varImage": "restorants1437580660.png",
      "varUrlImage": null,
      "varIcon": "",
      "varShortDescription": "",
      "intWebHits": "190",
      "intMobHits": "4",
      "varMetaTitle": "Restaurant Listing - Cayman Islands Business Portal",
      "varMetaKeyWord": "Restaurant Listing, Cayman Islands Business Portal, Restaurant Business, Online Business",
      "varMetaDescription": "Browse here Restaurant Listing and get right information about related business.",
      "intDisplayOrder": "1",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "dtCreateDate": "2015-07-22 10:57:40",
      "dtModifyDate": "2015-08-20 10:23:09",
      "varIPAddress": "",
      "varAdminUser": ""
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "2",
      "fk_Category": "0",
      "fk_CatList": "1,2,3,5",
      "varName": "Lounge",
      "varAlias": "lounge",
      "chrImageFlag": "U",
      "varImage": "",
      "varUrlImage": null,
      "varIcon": "",
      "varShortDescription": "",
      "intWebHits": "62",
      "intMobHits": "4",
      "varMetaTitle": "Lounge Listing - Cayman Islands Business Portal",
      "varMetaKeyWord": "Lounge Listing, Cayman Islands Business Portal, Lounge Business, Online Business",
      "varMetaDescription": "Browse here Lounge Listing and get right information about related business.",
      "intDisplayOrder": "2",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "dtCreateDate": "2015-07-22 10:59:34",
      "dtModifyDate": "2015-08-20 10:23:35",
      "varIPAddress": "",
      "varAdminUser": ""
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "3",
      "fk_Category": "0",
      "fk_CatList": "1,2,3,5",
      "varName": "Happy Hours",
      "varAlias": "happy-hours",
      "chrImageFlag": "U",
      "varImage": "movie-club1439218208.png",
      "varUrlImage": null,
      "varIcon": "",
      "varShortDescription": "",
      "intWebHits": "31",
      "intMobHits": "4",
      "varMetaTitle": "Happy Hours Listing - Cayman Islands Business Portal",
      "varMetaKeyWord": "Happy Hours Listing, Cayman Islands Business Portal, Happy Hours Business, Online Business",
      "varMetaDescription": "Browse here Happy Hours Listing and get right information about related business.",
      "intDisplayOrder": "3",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "dtCreateDate": "2015-07-22 11:00:17",
      "dtModifyDate": "2015-08-20 10:23:47",
      "varIPAddress": "",
      "varAdminUser": ""
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "4",
      "fk_Category": "0",
      "fk_CatList": "1,2,3,5",
      "varName": "Activities",
      "varAlias": "activities",
      "chrImageFlag": "U",
      "varImage": "outdoor-sports1439218224.png",
      "varUrlImage": null,
      "varIcon": "",
      "varShortDescription": "",
      "intWebHits": "33",
      "intMobHits": "4",
      "varMetaTitle": "Activities Listing - Cayman Islands Business Portal",
      "varMetaKeyWord": "Activities Listing, Cayman Islands Business Portal, Activities Business, Online Business",
      "varMetaDescription": "Browse here Activities Listing and get right information about related business.",
      "intDisplayOrder": "4",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "dtCreateDate": "2015-07-22 11:01:11",
      "dtModifyDate": "2015-08-20 10:23:58",
      "varIPAddress": "",
      "varAdminUser": ""
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "11",
      "fk_Category": "0",
      "fk_CatList": "1,2,3,5",
      "varName": "Movie Clubs",
      "varAlias": "movie-clubs",
      "chrImageFlag": "U",
      "varImage": "movie-club1437736241.png",
      "varUrlImage": null,
      "varIcon": "",
      "varShortDescription": "",
      "intWebHits": "8",
      "intMobHits": "4",
      "varMetaTitle": "Movie Clubs Listing - Cayman Islands Business Portal",
      "varMetaKeyWord": "Movie Clubs Listing, Cayman Islands Business Portal, Movie Clubs Business, Online Business",
      "varMetaDescription": "Browse here Movie Clubs Listing and get right information about related business.",
      "intDisplayOrder": "5",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "dtCreateDate": "2015-07-24 06:10:41",
      "dtModifyDate": "2015-08-20 10:24:14",
      "varIPAddress": "",
      "varAdminUser": ""
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "10",
      "fk_Category": "0",
      "fk_CatList": "1,2,3,5",
      "varName": "Motel",
      "varAlias": "motel",
      "chrImageFlag": "U",
      "varImage": "motel1437736219.png",
      "varUrlImage": null,
      "varIcon": "",
      "varShortDescription": "",
      "intWebHits": "7",
      "intMobHits": "4",
      "varMetaTitle": "Motel Listing - Cayman Islands Business Portal",
      "varMetaKeyWord": "Motel Listing, Cayman Islands Business Portal, Motel Business, Online Business",
      "varMetaDescription": "Browse here Motel Listing and get right information about related business.",
      "intDisplayOrder": "6",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "dtCreateDate": "2015-07-24 06:10:19",
      "dtModifyDate": "2015-08-20 10:24:38",
      "varIPAddress": "",
      "varAdminUser": ""
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "9",
      "fk_Category": "0",
      "fk_CatList": "1,2,3,5",
      "varName": "Resorts",
      "varAlias": "resorts",
      "chrImageFlag": "U",
      "varImage": "resort1437736195.png",
      "varUrlImage": null,
      "varIcon": "",
      "varShortDescription": "",
      "intWebHits": "8",
      "intMobHits": "4",
      "varMetaTitle": "Resorts Listing - Cayman Islands Business Portal",
      "varMetaKeyWord": "Resorts Listing, Cayman Islands Business Portal, Resorts Business, Online Business",
      "varMetaDescription": "Browse here Resorts Listing and get right information about related business.",
      "intDisplayOrder": "7",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "dtCreateDate": "2015-07-24 06:09:55",
      "dtModifyDate": "2015-08-20 10:25:18",
      "varIPAddress": "",
      "varAdminUser": ""
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "8",
      "fk_Category": "0",
      "fk_CatList": "1,2,3,5",
      "varName": "Indoor Sports",
      "varAlias": "indoor",
      "chrImageFlag": "U",
      "varImage": "indor-sports1437736159.png",
      "varUrlImage": null,
      "varIcon": "",
      "varShortDescription": "",
      "intWebHits": "8",
      "intMobHits": "4",
      "varMetaTitle": "Indoor Sports Listing - Cayman Islands Business Portal",
      "varMetaKeyWord": "Indoor Sports Listing, Cayman Islands Business Portal, Indoor Sports Business, Online Business",
      "varMetaDescription": "Browse here Indoor Sports Listing and get right information about related business.",
      "intDisplayOrder": "8",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "dtCreateDate": "2015-07-24 06:09:19",
      "dtModifyDate": "2015-08-20 10:25:28",
      "varIPAddress": "",
      "varAdminUser": ""
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "7",
      "fk_Category": "0",
      "fk_CatList": "1,2,3,5",
      "varName": "Outdoor Sports",
      "varAlias": "outdoor-sports",
      "chrImageFlag": "U",
      "varImage": "outdoor-sports1437736124.png",
      "varUrlImage": null,
      "varIcon": "",
      "varShortDescription": "",
      "intWebHits": "6",
      "intMobHits": "4",
      "varMetaTitle": "Outdoor Sports Listing - Cayman Islands Business Portal",
      "varMetaKeyWord": "Outdoor Sports Listing, Cayman Islands Business Portal, Outdoor Sports Business, Online Business",
      "varMetaDescription": "Browse here Outdoor Sports Listing and get right information about related business.",
      "intDisplayOrder": "9",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "dtCreateDate": "2015-07-24 06:08:44",
      "dtModifyDate": "2015-08-20 10:25:44",
      "varIPAddress": "",
      "varAdminUser": ""
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "6",
      "fk_Category": "0",
      "fk_CatList": "1,2,3,5",
      "varName": "Bars",
      "varAlias": "bars",
      "chrImageFlag": "U",
      "varImage": "bars1437736088.png",
      "varUrlImage": null,
      "varIcon": "",
      "varShortDescription": "",
      "intWebHits": "8",
      "intMobHits": "4",
      "varMetaTitle": "Bars Listing - Cayman Islands Business Portal",
      "varMetaKeyWord": "Bars Listing, Cayman Islands Business Portal, Bars Business, Online Business",
      "varMetaDescription": "Browse here Bars Listing and get right information about related business.",
      "intDisplayOrder": "10",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "dtCreateDate": "2015-07-24 06:08:08",
      "dtModifyDate": "2015-08-20 10:26:07",
      "varIPAddress": "",
      "varAdminUser": ""
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "5",
      "fk_Category": "0",
      "fk_CatList": "1,2,3,5",
      "varName": "Night Clubs",
      "varAlias": "night-clubs",
      "chrImageFlag": "U",
      "varImage": "night-clubs1437736013.png",
      "varUrlImage": null,
      "varIcon": "",
      "varShortDescription": "",
      "intWebHits": "8",
      "intMobHits": "4",
      "varMetaTitle": "Night Clubs Listing - Cayman Islands Business Portal",
      "varMetaKeyWord": "Night Clubs Listing, Cayman Islands Business Portal, Night Clubs Business, Online Business",
      "varMetaDescription": "Browse here Night Clubs Listing and get right information about related business.",
      "intDisplayOrder": "11",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "dtCreateDate": "2015-07-24 06:06:53",
      "dtModifyDate": "2015-08-20 10:26:18",
      "varIPAddress": "",
      "varAdminUser": ""
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "15",
      "fk_Category": "0",
      "fk_CatList": "3,5",
      "varName": "Family Tours",
      "varAlias": "family-tours",
      "chrImageFlag": "U",
      "varImage": "resort1439218271.png",
      "varUrlImage": null,
      "varIcon": "",
      "varShortDescription": "",
      "intWebHits": "5",
      "intMobHits": "4",
      "varMetaTitle": "Family Tours Listing - Cayman Islands Portal",
      "varMetaKeyWord": "Family Tours Listing, Cayman Islands Portal, Family Tours, Online Listing",
      "varMetaDescription": "Browse here Family Tours Listing and get right information about related listing.",
      "intDisplayOrder": "13",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "dtCreateDate": "2015-08-08 05:18:34",
      "dtModifyDate": "2015-08-20 10:27:03",
      "varIPAddress": "",
      "varAdminUser": ""
    }, {
      "intGlCode": "17",
      "fk_Category": "0",
      "fk_CatList": "3,5",
      "varName": "Excursions",
      "varAlias": "excursions",
      "chrImageFlag": "U",
      "varImage": "business-cate-icn1439029237.png",
      "varUrlImage": null,
      "varIcon": "",
      "varShortDescription": "",
      "intWebHits": "5",
      "intMobHits": "4",
      "varMetaTitle": "Excur Listing - Cayman Islands Portal",
      "varMetaKeyWord": "Excur Listing, Cayman Islands Portal, Excur, Online Listing",
      "varMetaDescription": "Browse here Excur Listing and get right information about related listing.",
      "intDisplayOrder": "15",
      "chrPublish": "Y",
      "chrDelete": "N",
      "dtCreateDate": "2015-08-08 05:20:37",
      "dtModifyDate": "2015-08-20 10:27:48",
      "varIPAddress": "",
      "varAdminUser": ""
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: What about [`JSON.parse(data)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: In `success` method the return parameter `data` will be an javascript object. so you can directy access the json fields like this `data.Status`

Comment: If you want to format the data as json proper use JSON.parse(data) ....  look into the @Spencer Answer. (hope you have Jquery )

Comment: @Kesavan-yes thats true..but i dont have idea..how to get "rate type values" and all that array..:(

Comment: @JigarMakwana, if you want to get `rate type values` then your JSON is incorrect. to get the array it should be like `name:[array]` not `name,[array]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get to the data something like this:

(You may not need the JSON.parse, if that throws and error take it out and just use data)

```
 $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url:  API_HOST+'/webservice/Get_FilterDetails',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'caymanauth': caymanauth
        },
          data: '&Catid='+Catid
    }).success(function (data) {
        var myData = JSON.parse(data);
        // myData is now regular javascript objects and arrays
        console.log(myData);
    }).error(function () {
        alert("error");
    });
```

What's weird about your data is the array in the Details field.

It contains both Strings like "Rate Type" and Arrays, this is unusal

So you'll just need to iterate through the Details array looking for the String which matches what you are looking for "Rate Type" etc. and then take then next element as the array

```
for(var i=0; i < data.Details.length - 1; i++){
   if(data.Details[i] == "Rate Type"){
      return data.Details[i + 1]; // the array for "Rate Type"
   }
}
```

Comment: but how to get "rate type" and list type array values..:(

Comment: See my edit, loop through with an index and take the next one

Comment: thank you so much..its the best answer,,,i got it..thanks sir you saved my day...:)

Comment: sir can you pls make one more help..how to loop for the rate types array..pls